# How would you be able to achieve real-time video with Websocket?

Tags: websocket

Suppose I have this web application client that *connects/subscribes* to a Websocket server. In which this websocket server sends the binary sent from clients to subscribers.

The client sends chucks of `webm` recorded video (e.g. every 1 second) then the server sends those chucks to every client to display the video stream.

My issue here is when the network  slows down then the sending of the "buffer" webm will pile up and a noticeable lag will be displayed. So if there's a connection problem for 15 seconds, then there will be this 15 chucks to send then the WebSocket server will just broadcast those chucks to subscribers causing those clients to playback a stream that is 15 seconds in the past, so this become totally not real-time.

What is the general approach to be able to achieve real-time video with Websocket?

*ps. I understand there's WebRTC, but in my case, I have to use Websocket.*

Comment: you can try adding a timestamp to your chunks and drop them before sending or in the server if you detect they're too far behind. The chance of that working good is low though.

Comment: @PhilippHancke I just created a websocket server then pushing media from the browser, playback is actually quite fast. I even tried to stream a movie, on top of that video chunks encoded in base64

Comment: Then network simulated to "Regular 3g" and playback is still okay.